# How do I derive the world coordinate of a point, given it's 2d image plane location, and depth value?

Tags: opencv, graphics

I have the following data:

- camera matrix
- 2d location of a feature in my image plane
- depth map value associated with my feature

My question is, how do I derive the object/world coordinate of my feature?

Comment: look at the formula of projection (how image pixel location is computed from 3D position) and "invert" that process.

Comment: What is the formula you are referring to?

Comment: 2.2.1.0. C http://www.epixea.com/research/multi-view-coding-thesisse8.html

Comment: or just use my comments and answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265245/extracting-3d-coordinates-given-2d-image-points-depth-map-and-camera-calibratio/31266627#31266627

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera matrix is:

```
[[fx 0  cx]
 [0  fy cy]
 [0  0  1 ]]
```

where `fx` and `fy` are the focal length in pixels. Since `fx` and `fy` are in pixels you can just use similar triangles to get the `x` and `y` coordinates:

```
x / z = (x_pixel - cx) / fx
y / z = (y_pixel - cy) / fy
```

or

```
x = (x_pixel - cx)/fx * z
y = (y_pixel - cy)/fy * z
```

You may have to multiply by -1 depending on how your coordinate systems are defined.