# Point cloud from depth map of distance values

Tags: point-clouds, color-depth

I have a depth map (500x290) and I want to obtain point cloud from it (x,y,z coordinates). The depth map data is produced by a perspective camera of 120 degrees horizontal field of view and 45 degrees of vertical field of view, therefore, the intrinsic parameter matrix is as follows:

```
         144.33    0     250
     K =   0     350.06  145
           0       0      1
```

the values in the depth map corresponding to the distance to the object (i.e. the norm of the vector (x, y, z)) and not only its Z component (depth). with all this information how can I calculate the x,y and z coordinates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting 3D coordinates given 2D image points, depth map and camera calibration matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265245/extracting-3d-coordinates-given-2d-image-points-depth-map-and-camera-calibratio)

Comment: nope. it is not the same thing. the sensor is not Kinect.

Comment: that doesn't matter. check out the formula how to compute the X,Y,Z values. it is the same concept.

Comment: I have tried and it doesn't work. this is my data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NlH7fxkSOZjcVSrtg2CB8gcUGFDONG21 and this is the depth image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14zJoJku7Y7-gs7iaGtReLq8scy-uSMeE let me know if you could correctly construct the scene without distortion (with the abovementioned information of the sensor). good luck.